# HTML Son element can't rewrite its property if father element has put property onto it

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I first write the first version, `world` is still blue. When I modify it to second version, `world` doesn't turn blue.

The first version use `class="Class` on the father element, so that son elements can all use this property. But I want to modify son element's property. It turns out that modification doesn't work as expected.

Then I tried second version. Instead of putting `class="Class"` on the `<div>` tag, I use `class="Class` on each son element. At this time, the modification worked.

`null` means color still follows original set property in css file.

`unset` means clear this property value and set it to default value.

CSS file as follows:

```
.Class {
    color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

first version

```
<div class="Class">
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <h1 id="hello">hello</h1>
    <h1 id="world">world</h1>
    <script>
        let hello = document.querySelector("#hello");
        let world = document.querySelector("#world");
        hello.style.color = null;
        world.style.color = "unset";
    </script>
</div>
```

second version

```
<div>
    <h1 class="Class">hello</h1>
    <h1 id="hello" class="Class">hello</h1>
    <h1 id="world" class="Class">world</h1>
    <script>
        let hello = document.querySelector("#hello");
        let world = document.querySelector("#world");
        hello.style.color = null;
        world.style.color = "unset";
    </script>
</div>
```

For the sake of convenience, we usually choose the first version, because it doesn't need to add `class="Class"` on every son element tag. However, it will cause the problem mentioned above. Why the problem arises? And is there other way to still use `class="Class"` on the father element, and can change son element's property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version can be modified as following in order to have the text colour on `world` as blue:

```html
<div>
    <h1 class="Class">hello</h1>
    <h1 id="hello" class="Class">hello</h1>
    <h1 id="world" class="Class">world</h1>
    <script>
        let hello = document.querySelector("#hello");
        let world = document.querySelector("#world");
        hello.style.color = null;
    </script>
</div>
```

Setting `world.style.color = "unset";` in first case was setting `#world` element colour to the inherited `color` value from parent, which was blue.

The [`initial value`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color#Description) for `color` property is expected to be black, which is what setting `color` to `unset` in the second case would apply.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

Comment: Thank you! I realized I mixed the concept between `unset` and `initial`. In fact, I forget to search the document. Next time I will search the document first.

Answer (score 1):

use the keyword `initial` instead of `unset` to achieve what you want.

```js
        let hello = document.querySelector("#hello");
        let world = document.querySelector("#world");
        hello.style.color = null;
        world.style.color = "initial";
```

```css
.Class{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="Class">
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <h1 id="hello">hello</h1>
    <h1 id="world">world</h1>
</div>
```